# Javascript variable undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please have a look at this code.

```
$('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
$('#groupname').val(prompt('Enter your Group:', ''));
alert($('#displayname').val());
alert($('#groupname').val());
```

I read values for two variables displayname and groupname respectively through javascript prompts. Then when i alert these two variables displayname alerts the real value,whereas groupname is alerted as undefined. I could not find any syntactical errors. What can be the possible reason ? Thank You in advance.

Comment: `#displayname` and `#groupname` are (or should be) elements on the page, not variables. I don't know if that's what you meant by "variables", but I thought I would clarify in case of confusion. To use variables, it should be `var groupName = someValue;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have element with particular id, so it will throw an `undefined` error.

Please review the following code:

```
<input id="displayname">
<input id="groupname">

$('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
$('#groupname').val(prompt('Enter your Group:', ''));
alert($('#displayname').val());
alert($('#groupname').val());
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/St83V/